# Applying background color to the whole page in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to apply background colour to my react app and I am using the Grid structure. Whenever I give try to apply the background colour it just colours up-to where my Grid is being used. Any suggestions or solutions are much appreciated for the same.

React version being used: 18.2.0
Material-UI: 5.8.6

Comment: You should add your current code and screenshots

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.